# How to run different winlogon shell for different user in windows?

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, winlogon

on Windows winlogon shell i specified to run a start.bat file which starts a program, now i want to run on windows logon specific programs for specific user.
for example, for user1 when windows starts it runs program1. for user2 when windows starts it runs program2. how can i do this ? if write on .bat how to know which user logined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use the username variable: %USERNAME% for finding the name of the user currently logged in.
2. Modify the start.bat file, use if-else conditionals for running programs based on username.
3. Run start.bat at logon.

Comment: like this IF %USERNAME%==user1 (start program1.exe )?

Comment: logically, yes. Test it and let me know how it works.

Comment: do you know how to start taskbar,startmenu etc from .bat file because when just start explorer.exe it does not start taskbar only windows explorer?

Comment: Is this related to your original question?

Comment: yes, when user1 logins it must start windows as normally but it starts only explorer.